# Whats the difference between Cookie SESSION= and session_id in database for spring session

Tags: spring-jdbc, spring-session

I am using spring session with JDBC postgres for session management. Whenever a new session gets created spring creates it and send the `sessionid` back to the browser in the cookie parameter `SESSION` and browser sends it back for every subsequent requests and things work fine. But the value in session_id in the postgres table `spring_session` is different form the `SESSION` sent back initially in cookie. Is this the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

Starting with Spring Session 2.0, `DefaultCookieSerializer` uses Base64 encoding by default. So what you're actually seeing as session cookie value is the Base64 encoded session id.

If you wish to restore the previous (Spring Session 1.x) default, you can explicitly configure `DefaultCookieSerializer` bean with [`useBase64Encoding`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.5.RELEASE/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/DefaultCookieSerializer.java#L302-L304) property set to `false`.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the advantage of using base64 encoding here? What purpose does it serve?